# Sitefinity custom modules

Tags: sitefinity

I have got some sample code for creating a custom module from here:

[Custom Sitefinity module sample](http://blogs.sitefinity.com/Ivan/Posts/09-01-25/Sitefinity_3_6_beta_-_sample_bare_bones_module_on_the_new_backend_architecture.aspx)

On the BooksListView.ascx it says "Display list of books here." but I am unsure of how to do this. Can anyone help or even better have a completed sample module.

I am using Sitefinity 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Introduction to Sitefinity Intra-Site Module Creation webinar](http://www.sitefinitywatch.com/blog/09-04-20/Introduction_to_Sitefinity_Intra-Site_Module_Creation.aspx) was recently posted online.

In addition, several blog posts and samples were posted on this subject to the [Sitefinity Developer Blogs](http://blogs.sitefinity.com/).

Comment: I have been waiting for that webinar to appear online, thanks.

Comment: @Gabe, I'm having trouble with custom intra-site modules in SF 5.1 not installing. I've looked at the SDK sample and mimicked what it's doing, but it just won't work. How can we debug install problems? PS. It won't even stop at a breakpoint in the install method